# having trouble with UIImageView initWithImage and accessing the element at index

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I am getting this warning.  Not sure what I need to do fix.  New to objective-C.  Doesn't seem to like this line and app crashes after getting to this line:

```
 UIImageView *tmp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[data objectAtIndex:index]];
```

Warning I am getting:

> /test/ViewController.m:186:89: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSNumber *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')

ViewController.m file:

```
@interface ViewController () <UICollectionViewDataSource_Draggable, UICollectionViewDelegate>
{

    NSMutableArray *data;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    NSNumber *index = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    for (UIView *subview in cell.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    UIImageView *tmp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[data objectAtIndex:index]];
    [cell addSubview:tmp];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why does your `data` array seem to contain both `NSNumber` objects and `UIImage` objects?

Answer (score 0):

The method `objectAtIndex:` requires NSUInteger argument. Pass `index.integerValue` value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is strange, since you're accessing the same Array for both index and the image! Why isn't the `data` array just holding the images? Then you could just call `UIImage * image = [data objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];`

Anyways...

With your current question, you just have to change:

```
NSNumber *index = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
UIImageView *tmp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[data objectAtIndex:index]];
```

with:

```
NSNumber *indexNumber = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImageView *tmp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[data objectAtIndex:indexNumber.intValue];
```

---

I want to point out that you should create a `CustomCollectionViewCell` with a property called `imageView` so you can change the image, instead of removing and adding imageViews every time. Plus the `data` array that only holds images.
It would look like:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Dequeue or initialize a new custom cell
    CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.imageView.image = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

You should also have `data` as a property:

```
@property NSMutableArray *data;
```

and use it with `self.data` so it's clear that it's a property.